# How do I add files to the application bundle in a Flutter Mac app?

Tags: macos, flutter

I have a file `/assets/foo`, that I want to appear in the Mac App bundle for my Flutter app. I've tried adding it to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    /assets
```

But it doesn't appear in `build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app` anywhere. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is it a typo ? in pubspec.yaml , you need to use - not / , such as - assets/foo/

Comment: Ah yeah, oops! However I have also since learned that `assets` embeds its files in the main binary, so it isn't the right solution anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to add assets for use by Flutter/Dart code, or to be loaded from native code? The solutions are different depending on the goal.

Comment: I want to use it from native code. It's an executable that I run using `Process.start()`.